# How do I get the horizontal and vertical scroll bar position of TWinControl such as TSynEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, synedit

In Delphi, in many TWinControl descendants, such as in my exact case, the TSynEdit control, how would I read the horizontal and vertical scroll bar position?

I have been searching around in the source code for my particular control, and in the base class documentation for TWinControl, and can't figure it out.

Is there a general VCL specific way to do this, or should I do this via Win32 API calls?

Comment: Are you tried using the [GetScrollBarInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787581(v=vs.85).aspx) function?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work for me, with either OBJID_CLIENT or OBJID_HSCROLL, but maybe I'm doing that wrong.  `if GetScrollBarInfo(SynEditCtrl.Handle, Integer(OBJID_CLIENT), SB) then ...` is returning false.

Comment: I can get pretty close using `SynEditCtrl.LeftChar` which will be 0 if the horizontal scroll position is all the way left.

Comment: This works for me http://pastebin.com/Xwywf04D

Comment: That must be correct, RRUZ. Something must be weird in my exact case. Maybe you can't call this in the context of WM_PAINT.  I think this would be a better question if I change this to ask "for any TWinControl" because I don't see any such question here. Your answer is good. You could post that. I don't see any duplicate of this question on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`GetScrollBarInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787581(v=vs.85).aspx) function is the way to get the scrollbars position of any TWinControl. You must pass the handle of the control, an `OBJID_VSCROLL` or `OBJID_HSCROLL` value and a  [`SCROLLBARINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787535(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to return the data.

Check this sample

```
var
 LBarInfo: TScrollBarInfo;
begin
 LBarInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(LBarInfo);
 if GetScrollBarInfo(SynEdit1.Handle, Integer(OBJID_VSCROLL), LBarInfo) then
  ShowMessage(Format('Left %d Top %d Height %d Width %d', [LBarInfo.rcScrollBar.Left, LBarInfo.rcScrollBar.Top, LBarInfo.rcScrollBar.Height, LBarInfo.rcScrollBar.Width]));
end;
```

Comment: IN my very weird case, I am seeing that I need to do this at some time other than during my particular TWinControl's owner-draw paint events.